# Why do the properties of SQL Server show database bigger than it really is?

Tags: sql-server, size

In our SQL Server database properties, our database size is shown as 67069.081 MB but when we run this script

```
Create Table #Temp(Name sysname, rows int, reserved varchar(100), data varchar(100),    index_size varchar(100), unused varchar(100))

exec sp_msforeachtable 'Insert Into #Temp Exec sp_spaceused ''?'', ''true''' 

Select  SUM(CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(data, ' KB', ''))) as d From #Temp

Drop Table #Temp
```

result is 7650088 KB nearly 7470.7890625 MB

67069.081, 8.97750966316 times bigger than 7470.7890625

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server database properties returns size of data and log files. (It's the same as `sp_spaceused` without any arguments.) `sp_spaceused table` returns size of the table (i.e., part of data file) - it never takes into account transaction log - that's the missing part in the discrepancy you see.

As a background - database consists from data files (tables, indexes, management pages like GAM, SGAM) and transaction log files.

Comment: why this files so big and how can we reduce this file size? Also this files are necessary?

Comment: Run select size / 128. AS SizeInMB, * from sys.database_files;. If type_desc is logs, it's transaction log. You can shirnk data and log files if they don't need to be so big. But know that if they grow again, shrinking will only waste resources. (Check DBCC SHRINKFILE) However, in your case maybe the issue is that transaction log is set to full and you don't do log backups so the log grows and grows. Check select recovery_model_desc, * from sys.databases; for that DB.

Answer (score 0):

The tables do not have clustered indexes therefore you can not logically defragment them (rebuild indexes) completely. That is, the indexes are defragged but not the actual data.

Also, DELETEs from heaps (a table without a clustered index) do not deallocate space. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189245(v=sql.105).aspx for more

Solutions?

```
Add clustered indexes for a long term fix (subject to regular index maintenance)
Run DBCC SHRINKFILE with NOTRUNCATE to compact data.
```